# Use of getchar() in for statement does not work as expected

Tags: c, getchar

The code below does not work as expected, somebody can give me some suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i, k=0, j=0;
    char hex[50], c;
    for (i=0; (c=getchar()) != EOF && (c=getchar()) != '\n'; i++) {
        hex[i] = c;
        j++;
    }
    if (c == 'n') {
        hex[i] = 'n';
        i++;
    }
    hex[i] = '\0';
    for (k=0; k<i; k++) {
        printf("%c", hex[k]);
    }
    printf("\n%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);
    return 0;
}
```

if I input:

```
abc
```

I suppose the output should be:

```
abc
4 3 4
```

However, in my Xcode IDE the output is:

```
b
1 1 1
```

Somebody can help me to debug my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i, j, k, c;//The type of c must be int.
    char hex[50];

    for (j = i = 0; i < sizeof(hex)-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++, j++) {//The input part should be one.
        hex[i] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\n') {//n is typo as \n
        hex[i] = '\n';
        i++;
    }
    hex[i] = '\0';

    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        printf("%c", hex[k]);
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", i, j, k);//newline already include.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me why the type of c must be int? I will value c with hex[] that is char type.

Comment: @user7241487  It is necessary to compare with `EOF`. `getchar` return 0..255 and -1(`EOF`). 255(`'\xFF'` and `EOF`) should not be confused.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

```
for (i=0; (c=getchar()) != EOF && (c=getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
```

compiler evaluates `c=getchar()) != EOF` first and takes the first char as input. Then if it is true it evaluates `(c=getchar()) != '\n'`. Now value of `c` is `'b'`.

You should say

```
for (i=0; (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
```

because `c` is already initialized as `'a'`

EDIT: as @Stargateur says you should use `while` when you don't know how long the operation goes and when you are waiting for some input to end it. Use `for` loop for restricted operations like operating on known number of items (for example array of a struct).

Comment: I will add that this `for` loop should be transform to a `while` loop. Because a `for` loop is for iterate but here you don't iterate you loop until `getchar()` return `\n` or `EOF`. So a `while` loop will be more idiomatic.